# What is the meaning of starting a PowerShell one liner with a + (plus) sign

Tags: powershell

I've came across a PowerShell one liner script for which the very first character is a + (plus) sign and I was wondering what is the meaning of doing this.

Example that will give the Unicode code point for character 'A' :

```
+'A'['']
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A unary `+` works as an implicit cast to the type `int32`.

The parser will simply try to convert the value on the right-hand side to an integer.

Let's look at (and step through) your statement, much like the parser would:

```
+'A'['']
```

Let's try to "tokenize" that statement:

```
+ 'A' [ ''  ]
^  ^  ^  ^  ^
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  Array index close operator
|  |  |  Empty string
|  |  Array index open operator
|  Literal string of length 1 with value A
Unary + operator
```

In order to know whether we can apply the `+` operater, we'll need to evaluate the right-hand argument:

```
'A'['']
```

The only way we can index into a string (such as `'A'`), is by treating it as a `char[]`, and providing an integer value between the `[` and `]` operator. An empty string is not in itself an integer, but when implicitly converted to one, it becomes `0` (try `[int]""` or `'' -as [int]` in powershell to see this in action). Now the statement looks more like this:

```
'A'[0]
```

This `char` at index `0` is obviously `A`, and so that is now our right-hand argument, the character uppercase A.

We now apply the unary `+` and voila, we get the corresponding ASCII value for the char `A`, which happens to be `65`.

We could similarly have done:

```
+("A" -as [char])
```

Or, using Briantist's example:

```
"A" -as [char] -as [int]
```

---

If you ever wonder how the parser splits a certain statement into individual tokens, use the [`[PSParser]::Tokenize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psparser.tokenize(v=vs.85).aspx) method:

```
PS C:\> $errors = @()
PS C:\> $script = "+'A'['']"
PS C:\> $tokens = [System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize($script,[ref]$errors)
PS C:\> $tokens | select Content, Type
Content     Type
-------     ----
+       Operator
A         String
[       Operator
          String
]       Operator
```

Answer (score 5):

It's used in [code golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) to convert to a number. It's shorter than `[int]`.

The significance of `['']` is that the square brackets are being used to get a `[char]` from a string. The `''` is an empty string being coerced into a `0`.

The asker is referring to a solution to a specific problem, where one of the restrictions was that the digits 0 through 9 could not be used in the answer at all.

See the [PowerShell One-Liner Contest 2015](http://www.happysysadm.com/2015/06/powershell-oneliner-contest-2015-win.html) and [the explanation of this (rather brilliant) solution from the winner](http://www.happysysadm.com/2015/07/announcing-winner-of-powershell.html).

Comment: What is the significance of `['']` since it is required in the ops example

Comment: 'A'[''] is the same as 'A'[0], which is the first character of the string 'A'.  I'm guessing the code golf didn't allow digits, and this was the shortcut. Empty strings convert to 0 when changed to ints.

Comment: @MikeShepard I get it now.... It converts it to `char`. DIdnt make sense at first...  and the update mentions that now as well

Comment: @Matt and `['']` works no matter the length of the string, whereas `-as [char]` would only work on strings of length `1`